# MacBook Pro 2019 on Bootcamp windows 10 goes really hot

Tags: windows-10, macbook, boot-camp

I have got a new MacBook Pro 2019 and installed a windows 10 on it using bootcamp. MacBook on windows 10 goes really really hot. I have needed to buy some cooling device under macbook because temperatures without it went to almost 100 degrees Celsius. Now if I'm running only google chrome i have 70 degrees Celsius and I hear fans so its making me nervous. I have been looking for solutions but they are really too old and they not fix this issue. Any ideas why this is happening ??

[image]

Comment: Did you install the Windows support software? https://support.apple.com/HT204923

Comment: No I didn't, My data will be safe ??

Comment: Should be - but you should always have a backup anyway.

Comment: Nope :( Still my mac is getting hot and fans runs crazy

Comment: Hmm, not sure then, sorry. I found this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329590/macbook-pro-2017-heating-issue-while-running-windows-10-on-bootcamp

Comment: I don't know maybe windows 10 is doing this issue. Someone tried with Windows 7 ?